# Eclipse PDT: How do I get it to format my PHP arrays like VIM?

Tags: php, arrays, vim, eclipse-pdt, indentation

I've been struggling to get Eclipse to format my php arrays like vim indentation does.

What eclipse does (press CTRL+SHIFT+F)

```
<?php
$array = array(
'key1' => 'value1',
'key2' => array(
'child_key1' => 'child_value1',
'child_key2' => 'child_value2',
),
);
```

What vim does (press keys:gg=G)

```
<?php
$array = array(
  'key1' => 'value1',
  'key2' => array(
    'child_key1' => 'child_value1',
    'child_key2' => 'child_value2',
    ),  
  );
```

I've tried looking in Preferences>PHP>Code Style>Formatter and Preferences>PHP>Editor>Templates but haven't found anything.
Thanks in advance.
Kehan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Eclipse PDT Luna 4.4: Choose menu `Window \ Preferences`. Choose `PHP \ Code Style \ Formatter`.
Create new `Active profile` then press button `Edit`.

[image]

In tab `Indentation`, choose `Default indentation for array initializers` You should choose value `1` (however, default value is `2`).

[image]

(after press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> ) and result will like this:
[image]

Answer (score 8):

Check out this project.  Put the jar file in your eclipse/dropins folder, and then you can go to preferences/php/code style/formatter.  It has a cool "Align => column position in array" option under the "Miscellaneous" section (click the arrow on the options tab to expand) that does something similar to what you want.  Use Ctrl-Shift-F to format an entire file, or right-click a selection and checkout the "Source->Format..." options.

http://de.sourceforge.jp/projects/pdt-tools/releases/?package_id=8764

Comment: You can vote to try and get this feature added to PDT @ https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=320130

Comment: The project being dead, where can I find this jar right now ?

Comment: I still had the original jar, I added it to my github. I made some small modifications to comply with coding standards at my job.  You can also download the original version from in the bin directory: https://github.com/dmeybohm/Eclipse-PHP-Formatter

Answer (score 3):

Hmm looks like this is still a problem with PDT, See [stack related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338957/proper-indentation-in-array-initialization-pdt-zend-studio).

It suggests pushing tab on the first carriage return and the rest should follow the indentation after that. As for CTRL+SHIFT+F this will overwrite any manual formatting you have in place.

I don't know if you have used [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.org/) (with the PHP plug-in) before but this IDE is eclipse based and might have the formatting options you want, Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for that - problem is I use CTRL+SHIFT+F _all the time_. I'm trying aptana (again) will post feedback here.
Cheers,
K

Answer (score 1):

I have been using PDT formatter for several months and it does a great job so far.

I had to reinstall Indigo after I failed to get developer build 4.3 M5a running full-featured. Here is how I did:

- Installed Indigo (Classic)
- Added http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/release to Available Software Sites and installed PDT
- Saved the zip file (Dave Meybohm's answer) http://sourceforge.jp/downloads/users/1/1455/pdt_tools.formatter_1.5.0.v20120929.zip/ and added to the Available Software Sites as an archive and installed the formatter. Under Preferences -> PHP -> Code Style ->Formatter (PDT Tools) was available for customization.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/19702960/2709131

The one thing that was missing was:

`Line Wrapping > Expressions > Array initializers > Indentation policy > Indent by one`