# Wrong array initializer indentation while typing PHP in Eclipse

Tags: php, arrays, eclipse, indentation

I set my preferred array initializer indentation on Preferences > PHP > Code Style > Fromatter > Line Wrapping, but while typing array initializers indentation is wrong:

```
$arr = array([ENTER]
····[CURSOR])
```

while I'm expecting:

```
$arr = array([ENTER]
··[CURSOR]
)
```

like it happens editing Javascript code. Note that the wrong indentation happens only while typing, whereas an explicit CTRL+SHIFT+F indents array initializer correctly. (So not a duplicate of many other questions asking how to set indentation, since here indentation is set but not applied while typing.)

How can I get the correct indentation while typing array initializers?

Answer (score 4):

My settings on Zend Eclipse for PHP Developers, under `PHP` > `Code Style` > `Formatter`:

- `Indentation` > `Tab policy` > `Spaces`
- `Indentation` > `Indentation size` > `2`
- `Indentation` > `Tab size` > `2`
- `Indentation` > `Default indentation for array initializers` > `2`
- `Line Wrapping` > `Expressions` > `Array initializers` > `Indentation policy` > `Indent by one`

Comment: one of these helped to make it work. Probably the indentation policy flag. I needed to restart Eclipse. It didn't work without.

Comment: Great, it same with Drupal coding standard

Answer (score 3):

Try to set Indentation Policy to `Indent by one` (instead of `Default Indentation`) for `Method Declarations -> parameters`

Comment: It doesn't work. It seems that the PHP formatter rules don't affect the live-typing indentation (at least for array initializers).

Comment: @Heruan Try then with Formatter -> Tab policy = Spaces and Indentation Size = 1

Comment: That will set indentation by 1 space and that's not what I want. I guess Eclipse PDT has somehow hardcoded a double-indentation for array initializers that can't be overloaded by a formatter plugin.

Comment: @Heruan In my Eclipse Indigo I have this settings: Tab policy = Spaces, Identation size = 1, Default Indentation for Wrapped Lines = 2, Default Indentation for array Initializer = 2. And it works exactly as you are describing.

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse Juno, try with PHP -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Default indentation for array intializers = 1. It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my Windows instance, it is necessary to restart Eclipse to apply changes to this setting:

`PHP > Code Style > Formatter > Default indentation for array intializers`

On other instances it's not required. No idea why.